# ERB code is breaking the lines of code after it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I used the following code in my show.html.erb file to load a youtube video.  The video loads but any code after this is not executing.

```
<p>
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=@video.youtubeid%>"
  frameborder="0"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
<p>
  <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%=@video.youtubeid%>"
    frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
</p>
```

Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375325/rails-3-1-having-iframe-in-view-makes-layout-stop-rendering)

Comment: Key here is the `</iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `<%= 'no line break' -%>` syntax, as in:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= @video.youtubeid -%>"
frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Notice the extra dash at the end `-%>`

Comment: This only makes a difference if there is actual whitespace behind the closing ERB tag. This is not the case here.